# req.body is empty and req.file is undefined using fetch API to upload a file

Tags: node.js, express, multer, form-data

Using express and multer on the server. The code is like this:

```
const uploader = multer({
  storage: multer.diskStorage({
    destination: (_req, _file, cb) => cb(null, './uploads/'),
    filename: (_req, file, cb) => {
      cb(null, file.fieldname)
    },
  }),
})


router.put('/test', uploader.single('avatar'), (req, res) => {
  console.log(req.body, req.file)
  // Output: {} undefined
})
```

Client-side:

```
const formData = new FormData()
formData.append('key1', 'asdf')
formData.append('avatar', file) // file is retrieved from a file input

await fetch('/test', {
  method: 'PUT',
  body: formData
})
```

I confirmed that the request payload is properly sent in the network tab (reads something like):

```
------WebKitFormBoundaryuop9gTEEh3xan8vu
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="key1"

asdf
------WebKitFormBoundaryPmnN5cEmrrCPOAg9
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="avatar"; filename="avatar.jpeg"
Content-Type: image/jpeg

------WebKitFormBoundaryPmnN5cEmrrCPOAg9--
```

However, I cannot get anything on the server side. What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

The [Uploading a file](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch#uploading_a_file) example lack of some key code. You need to add an event listener for the `change` event of the `input` element. So that you can get the `file` from `input.files` property.

A working example:

`server.ts`:

```
import express from 'express';
import multer from 'multer';
import path from 'path';

const app = express();
const port = 3000;

const uploader = multer({
  storage: multer.diskStorage({
    destination: (_req, _file, cb) => cb(null, path.resolve(__dirname, './uploads/')),
    filename: (_req, file, cb) => {
      cb(null, file.fieldname);
    },
  }),
});

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  res.sendFile(path.resolve(__dirname, './index.html'));
});

app.put('/test', uploader.single('avatar'), (req, res) => {
  console.log('body: ', req.body);
  console.log('file: ', req.file);
  res.sendStatus(200);
});

app.listen(port, () => console.log(`HTTP server is listening on http://localhost:${port}`));
```

client `index.html`:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>
  <input type="file">
  <script>
    window.onload = function () {
      const input = document.querySelector('input[type="file"]')
      input.addEventListener('change', () => {
        const file = input.files[0]
        const formData = new FormData()
        formData.append('key1', 'asdf')
        formData.append('avatar', file)

        fetch('/test', {
          method: 'PUT',
          body: formData,
        }).then(res => res.text()).then(res => {
          console.log('res: ', res)
        }).catch(console.log)
      })

    }
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

The log of server side:

```
body:  [Object: null prototype] { key1: 'asdf' }
file:  {
  fieldname: 'avatar',
  originalname: 'a7947f21438966d97d5ec622fe473ec.jpg',
  encoding: '7bit',
  mimetype: 'image/jpeg',
  destination: '/Users/dulin/workspace/github.com/mrdulin/expressjs-research/src/stackoverflow/68172207/uploads',
  filename: 'avatar',
  path: '/Users/dulin/workspace/github.com/mrdulin/expressjs-research/src/stackoverflow/68172207/uploads/avatar',
  size: 40241
```

Request payload of client side:

```
------WebKitFormBoundarybnHanQq8UoHLqcbY
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="key1"

asdf
------WebKitFormBoundarybnHanQq8UoHLqcbY
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="avatar"; filename="a7947f21438966d97d5ec622fe473ec.jpg"
Content-Type: image/jpeg


------WebKitFormBoundarybnHanQq8UoHLqcbY--
```

Answer (score 0):

Turned out to be a problem with the request header setting `Content-Type: undefined` (my intention was to remove it from an existing headers object)--100% my fault for not posting the full request! Both the code in question and the more complete code by the answer works.